# Moving to the next line of data when the date changes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following code...

Sub test()

```
Workbooks("MAY10-Key Indicator Daily Reportcopy.xls").Sheets("Input").Activate
Set c = Range("B15:B45")
For Each cell In c
    If cell.Value = Range("I5").Value Then
        Workbooks("McKinney Daily Census Template NOV 10.xls").Sheets("McKinney").Range("C15:I15").Copy
        cell.Offset(0, 37).PasteSpecial
    End If
    Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False

If Cell.Value = Date Then
    Range(Cells(Cell.Row + 1, 3).Address, Cells(Cell.Row + 1, 9).Address).Select
    Cells(Cell.Row + 1, 3).Activate
   Exit For
End If

Next Cell
End Sub
```

In the WB(McKinney Daily Census Template...), I have a column of dates that match with another WB. When the date changes I need WB(McKinney...) to drop to the next line range. I.E

```
11/01/10 - C15:I15

11/02/10 - C16:I16

11/03/10 - C17:I17
```

What do I need to add to my code to accomplish this. Thanks

Comment: so when you open WB McKinney you want excel to automatically select the next empty row in columns C through I

Comment: yes, but they wont be empty. It will have data in it

Comment: @Xantec. Actually when I run the macro the next day I want it to automatically select the next row in column c through i

Comment: great, one final point to clear up and then i should be able to code it for you. is there a column that has the dates in it? if not, are the rows in C:I empty prior to the next day?

Comment: Yes. Column B15:B45 has dates for the current month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has been updated to be specific to the needs indicated in the comments.

```
Sub test()
    Dim MayCell As Range, MayC As Range
    Dim McCell As Range, McC As Range
    Dim McK As Workbook, MAY10 As Workbook
    Dim ChkDate As Variant

    Set MAY10 = Workbooks("MAY10-Key Indicator Daily Reportcopy.xls")
    'may need to change, if your MAY10 file name changes
    Set McK = Workbooks("McKinney Daily Census Template NOV 10.xls")
    'this may need to change for each month/year

    MAY10.Activate
    MAY10.Sheets("Input").Activate
    ChkDate = Range("I5").Value
    Set MayC = Range("B15:B45")
    For Each MayCell In MayC
        If MayCell.Value = ChkDate Then
            McK.Activate
            McK.Sheets("McKinney").Activate
            Set McC = Range("B15:B45")
            For Each McCell In McC
                If McCell.Value = ChkDate Then
                    Range(Cells(McCell.Row, 3).Address, Cells(McCell.Row, 9).Address).Copy
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next McCell
            MAY10.Activate
            MayCell.Offset(0, 37).PasteSpecial
            Exit For
        End If
    Next MayCell
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a compile error message that says... Exit For not within For...Next

Comment: can you update the code in your question with what it looks like now, with my addition added?

Comment: It is now updated.

Comment: ok, i have updated the code in my answer, including the code from your question. If you remove your Sub test() from your module and copy in all of the code in my answer it should work

Comment: It copies the first row data (date 11/01/10). But it does not move down to the next row of data when i change the date to 11/02/10, it just paste 11/01/10 data again for the next day

Comment: ok, so you do not want it to check against today's date? that is what it does presently; it will loop through the dates in column B (as defined by `Set C = Range("B15:B45")`) and if one of the dates is equal to today then it will select columns C through I in the row below that cell.

Comment: Cell.value = range("I5').value is a cell with the date on MAY10-Key Indicator. When I change the date from 11/01/10 to 11/02/10 or any other date, I want it to go into my McKinney Daily Census Template, find what ever date is in I5 and copy that row of data from C to I and paste it on the MAY10-Key Indicator on the row that has the same date in my date column.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. i have modified my code in light of your information. i think this should now :)

Comment: I get the error message object required @ For Each MayCell In MayC

Comment: oh sorry. change `Set C = Range("B15:B45")` to `Set MayC = Range("B15:B45")`

Comment: @Xantec.....It works!!! Thank you so much for all your time and help. Is there a way to save people who helped, for possible future questions?

Comment: the title of a question along with selected tag(s) enable others to find past questions.